# How to test an .equals() method using JUnit and Hamcrest

Tags: java, junit4, hamcrest

I have a class List (EDIT: that I wrote myself), with method List.equals, so I want to run something like

```
List list1 = new List();
List list2 = new List();
assertTrue(list1.equals(list2));
```

So using matchers and assertThat, I thought maybe

```
assertThat(list1.equals(list2), is(true));
```

But this is getting pretty silly...EDIT: perhaps I can write my own matcher

Is there a better way to check if my equals method is working correctly?

This is with JUnit4.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;    

...

assertThat(list1, equalTo(list2));
```

Comment: That's what I needed, it calls the .equals method automatically, I didn't realize that was an option.

Comment: The `is` matcher is also a synonym for `equalTo`.

Answer (score 1):

`assertEquals(list1, list2)` is the most straightforward way.

Comment: The question is about Hamcrest.

Comment: If this assert fails, the message would be quite convoluted.